Burnside's Lemma from Polya's Enumeration Theorem
All the sources I have found mention that Polya's Enumeration Theorem is a "generalization of Burnside's Theorem," but only seem to generalize the statement where a group $G$ is acting on a set of colorings of some set $X$. My question is: Using the statement of PET, can you recover the statement: Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a set $X$. Then the number of orbits is equal to the average number of fixed points.

do you know orbit-stabilizer theorem ?

@coiso sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding but I thought if $Y$ was a singleton then $|Y^X|$ is just size one?

I am doubtful BL follows nicely from unweighted PET, but both BL and unweighted PET are special cases of weighted PET (I posted an answer).

Burnside's Lemma is a special case of the weighted version of PET.
Suppose a finite group $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $Y$ is a set of "colors." The space $Y^X$ of colorings (or, functions $X\to Y$) carries an action of $G$ too. Suppose further that each possible color is assigned a weight, or integer vector, via a function $\phi:Y\to\mathbb{Z}^m$. For each possible weight $w\in\mathbb{Z}^m$, let $f_w$ denote the number of colors of weight $w$ (i.e. the size of the fiber $|\phi^{-1}(w)|$), and let $f(t)=\sum_w f_wt^w$ be the resulting generating function, where we abbreviate $t^w=t_1^{w_1}\cdots t_m^{w_m}$, or $t^k=(t_1^k,\cdots,t_m^k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Any coloring of $X$ has a total weight obtained by summing the weights of all the colors used (counted with multiplicity). Equivalent colorings (under the action of $G$) have the same weight, so configurations (equivalence classes of colorings) have well-defined weights too.
Let $c_k(g)$ denote the number of $k$-cycles of $g\in G$ considered as a permutation of $G$. Then
$$ Z_G(u_1,\cdots,u_n):=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} u_1^{c_1(g)}\cdots u_n^{c_n(g)} $$
defines the cycle-index polynomial of $G$'s action, where $n=|X|$.
Polya Enumeration (Weighted). The weight-generating function for the configurations is
$$ |Y^X/G|(t)=Z_G(f(t),f(t^2),\cdots,f(t^n)). $$
Note the unweighted version of PET follows from setting $f(t)=|Y|$ (the constant function).
Corollary: Burnside's Lemma. Set $f(t)=1+t$ and extract the $t$-coefficient from both sides of the equation. This is equivalent to having two colors with weights $0,1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and then counting the configurations with total weight $1$. Any coloring with total weight $1$ necessarily colors exactly one element of $X$ using the weight-$1$ color, so weight-$1$ colorings are in bijection with $X$. The action intertwines this bijection, so configurations correspond to orbits of $X/G$.
